# Net::FTP and open-uri hanging while trying to put binary file to from URL to FTP server

Tags: ruby, ftp, open-uri, net-ftp

I have a scenario where I have an S3 URL with binary content that needs to be transferred to an FTP server. I'm using `Net::FTP`, `open-uri`, and Ruby 2.0.0-p353.

```
require 'net/ftp'
require 'open-uri'

Net::FTP.open(x,y,z) do |ftp|
            ftp.putbinaryfile(open(an_s3_url), 'remote_filename', 4096)
```

What the code above does is create a temporary `open-uriXXYY-*` temp file in the current dir, but then hangs. I have no idea why. Interrupting the function produces the following trace:

```
home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:434:in `accept': Interrupt
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:434:in `transfercmd'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:543:in `block (2 levels) in storbinary'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:199:in `with_binary'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:542:in `block in storbinary'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:541:in `storbinary'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:690:in `putbinaryfile'
```

The workaround is to retrieve the file and then put it, but this feels clunky. Is there a reason I can't do it this way, or am I missing something obvious? Same problem with or without blocksize included.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use passive FTP -- this was the obvious(?!) thing I was missing.

It is by default set to false.

```
Net::FTP.open(x,y,z) {|ftp| ftp.passive = true ... }
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: I used `ftp.passive = true` and it worked like a charm